move the segment to its corresponding parent node
my requirement is to get common K18 segments where its having similar ALF and OND fields, with different subnodes P04Y,P04Z,P04,P03, i need to group them under its parent K18 segment. for example in my input first two K18 has same child nodes except P03, 3rd K18 has different child nodes, we need to club them together.
also we need to check P01/TP1 has same ID and RAS then we need to club PT2 under same TP1 segment.
Input:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT>
    <LEAV ONE="1">
        <EDI SEGMENT="1">
            <FIELD1>EDI</FIELD1>
        </EDI>
        <AK1 SEGMENT="1">
            <VW>RS</VW>
        </AK1>
        <K18 SEGMENT="1">
            <ALF>001</ALF>
            <OND>ACF</OND>
            <P04Y SEGMENT="1">
                <K_1>VALUE1</K_1>
            </P04Y>
            <P04Z SEGMENT="1">
                <REGN>HU</REGN>
            </P04Z>
            <P04 SEGMENT="1">
                <B_DOC>810</B_DOC>
            </P04>
            <P03 SEGMENT="1">
                <FIELD1>X</FIELD1>
                <SEQ>10</SEQ>
                <RNTAM>VALUE1</RNTAM>
            </P03>
        </K18>
        <K18 SEGMENT="1">
            <ALF>001</ALF>
            <OND>ACF</OND>
            <P04Y SEGMENT="1">
                <K_1>VALUE1</K_1>
            </P04Y>
            <P04Z SEGMENT="1">
                <REGN>HU</REGN>
            </P04Z>
            <P04 SEGMENT="1">
                <B_DOC>810</B_DOC>
            </P04>
            <P03 SEGMENT="1">
                <FIELD1>X</FIELD1>
                <SEQ>20</SEQ>
                <RNTAM>VALUE2</RNTAM>
            </P03>
        </K18>
        <K18 SEGMENT="1">
            <ALF>001</ALF>
            <OND>ACF</OND>
            <P04Y SEGMENT="1">
                <K_1>new value</K_1>
            </P04Y>
            <P04Z SEGMENT="1">
                <REGN>new</REGN>
            </P04Z>
            <P04 SEGMENT="1">
                <B_DOC>new value</B_DOC>
            </P04>
            <P03 SEGMENT="1">
                <FIELD1>X</FIELD1>
                <SEQ>20</SEQ>
                <RNTAM>VALUE2</RNTAM>
            </P03>
        </K18>
        <K18 SEGMENT="1">
            <ALF>001</ALF>
            <OND>FCB</OND>
            <P04Y SEGMENT="1">
                <K_1>VALUE1</K_1>
            </P04Y>
            <P04Z SEGMENT="1">
                <REGN>HU</REGN>
            </P04Z>
            <P04 SEGMENT="1">
                <B_DOC>810</B_DOC>
            </P04>
            <P03 SEGMENT="1">
                <FIELD1>X</FIELD1>
                <SEQ>000020</SEQ>
                <RNTAM>VALUE213</RNTAM>
            </P03>
        </K18>
        <K28 SEGMENT="1">
            <BCOUN>ES</BCOUN>
        </K28>
        <P01 SEGMENT="1">
            <FIELD1>10</FIELD1>
            <FIELD2>1</FIELD2>
            <P02 SEGMENT="1">
                <FIELD1>001</FIELD1>
            </P02>
            <TP1 SEGMENT="1">
                <ID>01</ID>
                <RAS>X</RAS>
                <PT2 SEGMENT="1">
                    <LINE>VALUE1</LINE>
                </PT2>
            </TP1>
            <TP1 SEGMENT="1">
                <ID>01</ID>
                <RAS>X</RAS>
                <PT2 SEGMENT="1">
                    <LINE>VALUE2</LINE>
                </PT2>
            </TP1>
        </P01>
        <P01 SEGMENT="1">
            <FIELD1>10</FIELD1>
            <FIELD2>1</FIELD2>
            <P02 SEGMENT="1">
                <FIELD1>001</FIELD1>
            </P02>
            <TP1 SEGMENT="1">
                <ID>01</ID>
                <RAS>X</RAS>
                <PT2 SEGMENT="1">
                    <LINE>VALUE1</LINE>
                </PT2>
            </TP1>
            <TP1 SEGMENT="1">
                <ID>01</ID>
                <RAS>X</RAS>
                <PT2 SEGMENT="1">
                    <LINE>VALUE2</LINE>
                </PT2>
            </TP1>
            <TP1 SEGMENT="1">
                <ID>02</ID>
                <RAS>X</RAS>
                <PT2 SEGMENT="1">
                    <LINE>VALUE2</LINE>
                </PT2>
            </TP1>
        </P01>
        <PS01 SEGMENT="1">
            <FIELD1>VALUE</FIELD1>
        </PS01>
    </LEAV>
</ROOT>

** Desired Output:**
<ROOT>
    <LEAV ONE="1">
        <EDI SEGMENT="1">
            <FIELD1>EDI</FIELD1>
        </EDI>
        <AK1 SEGMENT="1">
            <VW>RS</VW>
        </AK1>
        <K18 SEGMENT="1">
            <ALF>001</ALF>
            <OND>ACF</OND>
            <P04Y SEGMENT="1">
                <K_1>VALUE1</K_1>
            </P04Y>
            <P04Y SEGMENT="1">
                <K_1>new value</K_1>
            </P04Y>
            <P04Z SEGMENT="1">
                <REGN>HU</REGN>
            </P04Z>
            <P04Z SEGMENT="1">
                <REGN>new</REGN>
            </P04Z>
            <P04 SEGMENT="1">
                <B_DOC>810</B_DOC>
            </P04>
            <P04 SEGMENT="1">
                <B_DOC>new value</B_DOC>
            </P04>
            <P03 SEGMENT="1">
                <FIELD1>X</FIELD1>
                <SEQ>10</SEQ>
                <RNTAM>VALUE1</RNTAM>
            </P03>
            <P03 SEGMENT="1">
                <FIELD1>X</FIELD1>
                <SEQ>20</SEQ>
                <RNTAM>VALUE2</RNTAM>
            </P03>
        </K18>
        <K18 SEGMENT="1">
            <ALF>001</ALF>
            <OND>FCB</OND>
            <P04Y SEGMENT="1">
                <K_1>VALUE1</K_1>
            </P04Y>
            <P04Z SEGMENT="1">
                <REGN>HU</REGN>
            </P04Z>
            <P04 SEGMENT="1">
                <B_DOC>810</B_DOC>
            </P04>
            <P03 SEGMENT="1">
                <FIELD1>X</FIELD1>
                <SEQ>000020</SEQ>
                <RNTAM>VALUE213</RNTAM>
            </P03>
        </K18>
        <K28 SEGMENT="1">
            <BCOUN>ES</BCOUN>
        </K28>
        <P01 SEGMENT="1">
            <FIELD1>10</FIELD1>
            <FIELD2>1</FIELD2>
            <P02 SEGMENT="1">
                <FIELD1>001</FIELD1>
            </P02>
            <TP1 SEGMENT="1">
                <ID>01</ID>
                <RAS>X</RAS>
                <PT2 SEGMENT="1">
                    <LINE>VALUE1</LINE>
                </PT2>
                <PT2 SEGMENT="1">
                    <LINE>VALUE2</LINE>
                </PT2>
            </TP1>
        </P01>
        <P01 SEGMENT="1">
            <FIELD1>10</FIELD1>
            <FIELD2>1</FIELD2>
            <P02 SEGMENT="1">
                <FIELD1>001</FIELD1>
            </P02>
            <TP1 SEGMENT="1">
                <ID>01</ID>
                <RAS>X</RAS>
                <PT2 SEGMENT="1">
                    <LINE>VALUE1</LINE>
                </PT2>
                <PT2 SEGMENT="1">
                    <LINE>VALUE2</LINE>
                </PT2>
            </TP1>
            <TP1 SEGMENT="1">
                <ID>02</ID>
                <RAS>X</RAS>
                <PT2 SEGMENT="1">
                    <LINE>VALUE2</LINE>
                </PT2>
            </TP1>
        </P01>
        <PS01 SEGMENT="1">
            <FIELD1>VALUE</FIELD1>
        </PS01>
    </LEAV>
</ROOT>

** XSLT I used is below:**
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" expand-text="yes">
    <xsl:template match="LEAV">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, * except (K18, K28)"/>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="K18" composite="yes" group-by="ALF, OND">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, ALF, OND"/>
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()!* except (current-group()!(ALF, OND))" composite="yes" group-by="node-name(), @*, *">
                        <xsl:sequence select="."/>
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="K28"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="LEAV">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, * except (P01, PS01)"/>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="P01/TP11" composite="yes" group-by="ID, RAS">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, ID,RAS"/>
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()!* except (current-group()!(ID,RAS))" composite="yes" group-by="node-name(), @*, *">
                        <xsl:sequence select="."/>
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="P01,PS01"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>



Are there any elements to be used as a grouping or merge key to join K18 elements together? Are that solely the ALF and OND element values? Or do you even need to group/merge based on other and complex elements like the P04Y elements?

still need to check other group/merge based on all child nodes, example P04Y, P04Z,P03 all child nodes

after checking all K18, my input has only different segment as P03, so  i need to move them to K18 as unique

The stylesheet
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:template match="LEAV">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, * except (K18, K28)"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="K18" composite="yes" group-by="ALF, OND">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, ALF, OND"/>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()!* except (current-group()!(ALF, OND))" composite="yes" group-by="node-name(), @*, *">
            <xsl:sequence select="."/>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="K28"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>

seems to give the wanted result for your input sample, I am, however, not sure, I have understood your full requirements, the sole sample doesn't explain them detailed enough.
As for you edited XML input sample with additional elements and additional requirements, your attempt to use two templates for LEAV doesn't make sense, what might lead you in the right direction is
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:template match="LEAV">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, K18/preceding-sibling::*[not(self::K18)]"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="K18" composite="yes" group-by="ALF, OND">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, ALF, OND"/>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()!* except (current-group()!(ALF, OND))" composite="yes" group-by="node-name(), @*, *">
            <xsl:sequence select="."/>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="K18/following-sibling::*[not(self::K18)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="P01">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, TP1/preceding-sibling::*[not(self::TP1)]"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="TP1" composite="yes" group-by="ID, RAS">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, ID, RAS"/>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()!* except (current-group()!(ID, RAS))" composite="yes" group-by="node-name(), @*, *">
            <xsl:sequence select="."/>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="TP1/following-sibling::*[not(self::TP1)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Give that a try and post feedback.

in this xslt we are only checking if ALF and OND is same or not, but we also need to check if segments -> P04Y, P04Z,P04 is same or not, if its same then we need to move P03 to its K18

@CHAR, I don't think you have really understood what the <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()!* except (current-group()!(ALF, OND))" composite="yes" group-by="node-name(), @*, *">... is all about. But if you think you know what to implement then just do that. Why is your own code doing some sorting but no grouping or comparison?

my sincere apologies, i am trying to explain the requirement. XSLT you given is exactly working, but position of the P04Y,P04Z,P04 is coming at the last, i have updated the input and output. Please have a look and assist.

hello martin, i have tried for P01/TP1 grouping as well, in same xml, followed the same steps as you mentioned, its giving me same P01 segment, request you to have a look

@CHAR, your attempt to use two template matching the same LEAV elements doesn't seem to make sense, I have edited my answer to show how to match on LEAV to group and merge the content of K18 and to match on P01 to group and merge the content of TP1.  Please don't add any more input elements to this question, let's first try to establish whether we manage to solve the existing problem. Once we achieved that, and you have more complex input and requirements, you can ask a new, separate question on that.

thank you very much for your help, grouping is exactly working as expected, after grouping can we get P04Y,P04Z,P04 in one order under K18, currently its placing after P03. I haven't changed the input, but updated the output. i apologize, mistakenly i haven't given the sequence. Thanks for your time.

@CHAR, we could try to add some sorting like e.g. <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()!* except (current-group()!(ALF, OND))" composite="yes" group-by="node-name(), @*, *"><xsl:sort select="string(current-grouping-key()[1])"/>, that would sort the element alphabetically by the element name. Does that help/suffice? I am not sure where the sample output you have shown takes its order from to perform it in terms of XSLT code, perhaps it is better you raise that as an additional question where you explain what constitutes the order of the elements in the result.

thanks Martin, as you suggested i am not editing the input,   what i observed is if P01 has no TP1 segment then its completely removing the P01 node and giving blank  , no TP1 segment scenario is also exist.  Please suggest i can post new question if needed.

@CHAR, yes, ask a new question then, the code I have written doing e.g.  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, TP1/preceding-sibling::*[not(self::TP1)]"/> only makes sense if there are TP1 elements.
